# Is it possible to put the multiple date alarm with the this code in android?

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

In my Application i want to set the Different alarm on defferent date.
So is it possible with this code:

```
//For Broadcast Alarm
                alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent in = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
                pendingIntentOfTwoMonth = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, in, 0);

                // for the GST 20 June 2011
                Calendar calendar_GST_18_June_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_GST_18_June_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_GST_18_June_2011.set(2011, 5, 18, mHour, mMinute, 0);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,   calendar_GST_18_June_2011.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntentOfTwoMonth); 

                // for the GST 17 August 2011
                Calendar calendar_GST_17_August_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_GST_17_August_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_GST_17_August_2011.set(2011, 7, 17, mHour, mMinute, 0);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_17_August_2011.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntentOfTwoMonth);

                // for the GST 19 October 2011
                Calendar calendar_GST_19_October_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_GST_19_October_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_GST_19_October_2011.set(2011, 9, 19, mHour, mMinute, 0);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_19_October_2011.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntentOfTwoMonth);

                // for the GST 17 December 2011
                Calendar calendar_GST_17_December_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_GST_17_December_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_GST_17_December_2011.set(2011, 11, 17, mHour, mMinute, 0);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_17_December_2011.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntentOfTwoMonth);

                // for the GST 18 February 2012
                Calendar calendar_GST_18_February_2012 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_GST_18_February_2012.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_GST_18_February_2012.set(2012, 1, 18, mHour, mMinute, 0);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_18_February_2012.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntentOfTwoMonth);

                // for the GST 27 April 2012
                Calendar calendar_GST_27_April_2012 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_GST_27_April_2012.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar_GST_27_April_2012.set(2011, 3, 27, mHour, mMinute, 0);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_27_April_2012.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntentOfTwoMonth);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can. Why not test or by simply changing the timings to tomorrow or later today and then feedback?

Comment: Yes Sure i will do. But i just want to be sure it as because i have ctaken the same object of alarmManager for all alarm but different  calender time for the alarm. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Oh ok, I would say you only need one instance of alarmmanager as the multiplicity is 'one alarmmanager can have many alarms'. If you wanted to be better with cycles and memory, you could stop calling the current time every instance you setup an alarm and maybe reuse a few objects?

Comment: Then for that will you tell me the code ? how to do that to manage the memory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. You will only have 1 alarm, the last one you created. The reason for this is because the PendingIntent is the same. You need to use unique PendingIntents in order to get multiple alarms. I suggest reading the API docs on AlarmManager and Notifications.

Comment: So Should i have to make different pendingIntent for Every Different Alarm ?

Comment: check out this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29 it says "If there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, it will first be canceled. "

Comment: So if i want to add the More then one timer then how to do it ?

Comment: You need to create distinct pending intents. So using the same PendingIntent each time is causing it to only set 1 alarm, the last one you've set. Read the link, they discuss how the OS determines whether this is a distinct pending intent, or if it "matches" one of the ones it already has scheduled.

Comment: you could vary the requestCode, so that the PendingIntents are unique, even though they claim that the requestCode isn't currently used.